# Loading images from sd card/folder in gridview

Tags: android, image, gridview, dynamic

I want to load images from sd card or any specific folder in my android application and show a dialog `onClick`.
I tried it to do it with the code below,but application is stopping unexpectedly.
And what will be the contents of `main.xml`.
Please help.Thanks in advance.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private Bitmap[]mis_fotos;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;    }

public int getCount() {
    get_images();
    return mis_fotos.length;
    }

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;    }

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 150));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(mis_fotos[position]);
    return imageView;
}

private void get_images(){
    File directory = new File(Variables.PATH_FOTOS);   

    File[] archivos =directory.listFiles();
    mis_fotos= new Bitmap[archivos.length];

    for (int cont=0; cont<archivos.length;cont++){

        File imgFile = new  File(archivos[cont].toString());                
        mis_fotos[cont] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: you have activity class in your application?

Comment: Yea. I have a big application but for that i am trying to make the grid in seperate application.That's why activity is in application.